# ¿Cómo ordenar datos en columnas de datatables cuando la columna tiene una jerarquía (ej.: cuentas contables)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Estoy haciendo un catálogo de cuentas en php y mysql. Para facilitar uso DataTables para orden de datos y lo llevo de la siguiente manera:

[image: Catalogo de cuentas inicial]

El problema es que no quiero que se ordenen por el id sino más bien por el orden jerárquico de la columna *cuenta*. A mi código de Datatable lo tengo estructurado de la siguiente manera; ya ejecuté las maneras posibles para ordenas datos y lo que consigo es que me los ordene en orden número, es decir, 1,2,3,4,5,6 y luego 11,21,31,41,51,61, para luego llegar a las cifras de 4 dígitos, pero no consigo que respeten su orden jerárquico.

Acá les dejo cómo llevo configurado el DataTable:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    tabla = $('#tabla').DataTable({
      "ordering": true, // Con esto le estás diciendo que se pueda ordenar, ponlo a 'true'
      "order": [], // Aquí le dices que el criterio de ordenación primero esté vació , o lo que es lo mismo, ninguno
      'ajax': {
        'url': 'buscadorDatatable.php?tabla=catalogocuentas',
        'dataSrc': ''
      },
      select: 'multi',
      columns: [{
        data: null,
        orderable: true,
        defaultContent: '<input type="checkbox" class="check" />',
        className: 'check',
        targets: 0
      }, {
        data: 'id',
        orderable: false // Hacer la columna "id" no ordenable
      }, {
        data: 'cuenta',
        orderable: true // Hacer la columna "id" no ordenable
      }, {
        data: 'nombrecuenta'
      }, {
        data: 'naturaleza'
      }, {
        data: 'tipo'
      }, {
        data: 'nivel'
      }, {
        data: 'estatus'
      }, {
        data: 'saldoinicial'
      }, {
        data: 'saldofinal'
      }, {
        "defaultContent": '<div class="opciones-externas"><a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-primary editar"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a><a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-primary eliminar"><i class="icon-cancel text-danger"></i></a></div>'
      }],
      columnDefs: [{
          type: 'cuenta',
          targets: [3]
        } // Aplica el tipo de ordenamiento personalizado a la columna "cuenta"
      ],
      responsive: true,
      dom: 'Bfrtip',
      searching: false,
      aasorting: [],
      buttons: ['copy', 'print', 'excel', 'pdf'],
      processing: true,
      language: {
        "sProcessing": "Procesando...",
        "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
        "sZeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
        "sEmptyTable": "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
        "sInfo": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_",
        "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0",
        "sInfoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
        "sInfoPostFix": "",
        "sSearch": "Buscar:",
        "sUrl": "",
        "sInfoThousands": ",",
        "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
        "oPaginate": {
          "sFirst": "Primero",
          "sLast": "Último",
          "sNext": "Siguiente",
          "sPrevious": "Anterior"
        },
        "oAria": {
          "sSortAscending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
          "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: No entiendo a que te refieres con "que respeten el orden jerarquico"

Comment: A ese orden que se ve en la imagen
1,
11
1101
110101
2
21,
2101
210101

Y asi sucesivamente hasta llegar a nivel 6, ahi solo he mostrado dos niveles.

Comment: Has probado a desactivar la ordenación de la columna ID directamente en la tabla? En el <thead>, en la columna que lleva el título 'ID' colocas <th data-orderable="false">ID</th>

Comment: sigo sin entender, ahora hablas de niveles :S. Cual sería la salida esperada?

Comment: La salida esperada deberia de ser 
1.
1101
110102
11010203
siguiendo el patron inicial de 1 cambiar a 2.
2.
2101
210102
21010203

A 3
3.
3101
310102
31010203

A 4
4.
4101
410102
41010203

A 5
5.
5101
510102
51010203

A 6
6.
6101
610102
61010203


Y asi sucesivamente cambiando hasta llegar a 6 ya que son 6 cuentas contables.

El problema que yo tengo ahorita es que si yo agrego un registro que es numero de cuenta: 
11010204

Me lo esta dejando de ultimo en orden de id cuando que en realidad deberia de seguir el patron inicial del 1 ya que inicia con 1.

Comment: @JuanCarlos Si ya probe esa alternativa amigo.

Comment: @LopezChavez aunque ya respondieron a tu pregunta, recuerda editarla para agregar lo que comentaste acerca de la salida esperada, ya que es información relevante. Y por cierto, si la respuesta realmente te ha sido útil, no olvides [aceptarla](/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: Lo consigues ordenando como cadena; para evitar la autodetección (numérica) usa en la columna `sType='string'`.

Answer (score 0):

Las cuentas contables siguen una estructura de árbol, se ordenan fácilmente de menor a mayor ya que el nodo padre siempre es menor que sus hijos.

Lo que pasa es que a ti te faltan los ceros a la derecha de los nodos padres, supongamos que las cuentas contables están representadas con un número fijo de 10 dígitos, tu tienes un `1` cuando deberías tener un `1000000000` o un `1334` cuando deberías tener 1334000000`

Para convertir un `1` en `1000000000`, puedes usar la siguiente función:

```js
// El 10 representa la cantidad de ceros 
//                                |
//                                V
console.log("1".toString().padEnd(10,"0"));
console.log("123".toString().padEnd(10,"0"));
console.log("32323232".toString().padEnd(10,"0"));
```

Luego en la columna "Cuenta", el `data` lo pasamos con función para poder intervenir en ella y le creamos una propiedad oculta `row.cuentaEntera` que tendrá el valor de la cuenta con todos los cero a la derecha y usaremos ese valor para ordenar y no el valor que se muestra en pantalla que será `row.cuenta`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.example1').DataTable({
   columns: [{
      orderable: true,
       data: function ( row, type, val, meta ) {
         if (type === 'set') {
            row.cuentaEntera = val.toString().padEnd(10,"0");
            row.cuenta = val;
            return;
         }
         else if(type === 'display') return row.cuenta;
         else if(type === 'filter') return row.cuenta;
         else if(type === 'sort') return row.cuentaEntera;
         return row.cuenta;
      }
   }]
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.18/b-1.5.2/b-html5-1.5.2/b-print-1.5.2/datatables.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.18/b-1.5.2/b-html5-1.5.2/b-print-1.5.2/datatables.min.js"></script>

    <table class="example1 display nowrap" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Cuenta</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td>110101</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1101</td></tr>
            <tr><td>11010201</td></tr>
            <tr><td>110102</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1101030101</td></tr>
            <tr><td>110103</td></tr>
             <tr><td>11</td></tr>
            <tr><td>11010301</td></tr>
            
        </tbody>
    </table>
```